# Save and read selected card position in RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have list card. Every card has option: edit,deleteCard, information and defaultCard. When add first card this card automatically set card on border green. When we have more card we can selected card.But I have problem when select for example second card and next exit my app. When I trun my app and go my list card is selected first card but I select second card. How to save position selected card and next read selected position card.

[List Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7jLM.png)

this CardAdapter.class

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.CardViewHolder> {

    private int lastCheckedPos = 0;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Card> cardsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private MySharepreference mySharepreference;

    public CardAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Card> cardsList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.cardsList = cardsList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false);
        return new CardViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Card card = cardsList.get(position);
        databaseHandler = new CardDatabaseHandler(mContext);
        mySharepreference = new MySharepreference();

        holder.nameCard.setText(card.getNumberCard());
        holder.setCurrentDateText.setText(card.getCreateDate());
        holder.setExpirationDateText.setText(card.getExpirationDate());

        if (lastCheckedPos == position) {
            mySharepreference.saveNumberCard(mContext, card.getId());

            holder.cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bordercardview);
            holder.menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                Typeface custom_fonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
                Typeface custom_fonts_Bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
                    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.cardmenudefault);
                    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.editCardD:

                                    break;
                                case R.id.deleteCardD:

                                    break;
                                case R.id.informationD:

                                    break;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    popupMenu.show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder.cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bordercardviewwhite);
            holder.menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
                    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.cardmenu);
                    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.editCard:

                                    break;
                                case R.id.deleteCard:

                                    break;
                                case R.id.informationAboutCard:

                                    break;
                                case R.id.defaultCard:

                                    lastCheckedPos = position;
                                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    break;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    popupMenu.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cardsList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Store the position of your selected card using `onSaveInstanceState()` callback method.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    bundle.putInt("CARD_POSITION", 12);            
}
```

And in `onCreate()` add below code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        index = savedInstanceState.getString("CARD_POSITION");            
    }
}
```

Now you can assign this index to your recyclerview.

For reference have a look on [this link](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/).